# Is there a way to analyze the content of an email as the user is typing using Apps Scripts for Gmail?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, google-developers-console

I'm doing some research on this, and I wanted to perform certain actions on a draft email, is it possible to analyze as the user types and execute functions?
Something similar to a classic 'onChange' event on a draft email.
Also, I don't want the user to imperatively press the extension to open it, is it possible to open it once the user starts composing a new email?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** Unfortunately neither of your questions is possible.

**Explanation:**

You cannot attach a typical Apps Script to Gmail like the other Docs editors. Instead you need to create it as a [Google Workspace Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail). Add-ons have a different set of triggers called [manifest triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/workspace-triggers). For Gmail you have **compose triggers** and **contextual triggers**. You can also create [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#available_types_of_triggers) but the typical `onEdit()` or `onChange()` is not available for Gmail.

Now, the relevant manifest trigger for your use case is the compose trigger. The way to use it is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui#accessing_the_compose_ui):

> There are two ways to view an add-on's compose UI. The first way is to start composing a new draft or reply while the add-on is already open. The second way is to start the add-on while composing a draft.

As you can see, to fire the trigger the user needs to either interact with the add-on while the compose window is open, or have it open before composing a new message. The same applies to the contextual trigger. It's not possible for the app to act in the background without user input.

You can find the answer to your other question by checking the [compose actions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui) and [Gmail actions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/gmail-actions). In a nutshell, the actions allow the app to aid users to compose messages by inserting text, images or recipients, but they don't support reading the compose contents or capturing the user actions. This seems to be by design and is probably for privacy reasons.

I haven't tried it, but you may be able to use JavaScript in your interface to read the DOM, though this seems to be against add-on [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/guides/workspace-restrictions) and even if possible it wouldn't be efficient:

> Except for certain triggers, add-ons can't tell what a user does outside the add-on itself. For example, you can't detect when the user clicks on the host application toolbar. It is possible to poll for changes in a file's contents from a sidebar's client-side code, although you'll always have a slight delay.

Also:

> Google Workspace Add-ons must use card-based interfaces. The HTML/CSS interfaces supported by Editor Add-ons can't be used. Google Workspace Add-ons use a widget-based approach to building user interfaces.

It seems that the add-ons are just meant to automate certain actions when navigating through emails, but Google is being careful into not allowing apps to breach users' privacy.

##### References

- [Extending the compose UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui)
- [Gmail add-on actions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/gmail-actions)
- [Add-on restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/guides/workspace-restrictions)